# swift mutating method sent to immutable object

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsmutablearray

I just can't wrap my head around this error, I am trying to add a string to an array like I always do in objective-c, but swift gives me a weird error.

```
var fileArray:NSMutableArray = []

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
            self.fileArray.addObject(self.urlTextField.text)
            self.processURL()
        }))
```

ERROR:
**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'**

How `fileArray` is immutable? I declare it as MutableArray !!!!!!

EDIT:::
so turns out problem is the way I populate the array

```
fileArray = myDict?.valueForKey("fileList") as! NSMutableArray
```

this solved the problem

```
fileArray = myDict?.valueForKey("fileList")!.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
```

Comment: Are you sure that problem is related to `fileArray` object? Can you add exception breakpoint and check on what line app is crashing?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Could you check the type of `self.fileArray` by doing CMD+CLICK on it? That way you will know if it is indeed a weird Swift bug or if  `self.fileArray` is maybe something else than this NSMutableArray.

Comment: @EricD. I populate array in `viewLoad` from a `.plist` like `fileArray = myDict?.valueForKey("fileList") as! NSMutableArray` Do you think that might be the problem

Comment: @MordFustang Yes. That is a completely different situation than your question, and would be expected behavior.

Comment: Yes, it's the problem. `as! NSMutableArray` only makes compiler silent but not makes actual value to be mutable. You need call `mutableCopy` on result of `myDict?.valueForKey("fileList")` call.

Comment: @RobNapier ahhh so I need to add objects from dict array rather than doing `fileArray = myDict?.valueForKey("fileList") as! NSMutableArray` ??

Comment: Search for "NSPropertyListMutableContainers". It depends on how you're reading your plist.

Comment: @MordFustang Can you check if this works for you `fileArray = myDict?.valueForKey("fileList")!.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array does not become mutable just because you declare it as such or because you cast it as mutable with `as! NSMutableArray`. An array is only mutable if it is created as a mutable array with `[[NSMutableArray alloc] ....]` or by making a mutableCopy of an array.

(the same goes for dictionaries, strings, NSSet and NSData)

Answer (score 0):

As your array contains only a single type, I'd recommend to use Swift types, it's so much easier, `var` is mutable, `let` is immutable

```
var fileArray : Array<String> = []

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
            self.fileArray.append(self.urlTextField.text)
            self.processURL()
        }))
```